# How do I flag a question on Stack Exchange as having to be migrated to a specific Stack Exchange website that isn't in the list of suggested websites?

Tags: support, migration, vote-to-close

When flagging a question on Stack Exchange, we can ask for a migration to another Stack Exchange website. However the list is limited. How can I select a Stack Exchange website that isn't in the list?

E.g.:

[image]

Comment: You can not select it. You can however flag the question with a custom reason and notify the moderators to which [se] site you think it belongs better. Something I'm gonna have to do with your question, this is neither [meta] nor [meta.se] ;|

Comment: Thanks, I wish that we could indicate the adequate Stack Exchange site in the same page (Flagging > Closing > off topic > Migration). I didn't post this question on meta webapps as it is not specific to webapps.stackexchange.com, but any stackexchange.com site, and I don't believe there exists a meta meta. I subsequently chose Webapps as stackexchange can qualified as a Q&A web app (thanks Steve for making the meaning of app totally equivoque).

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt The meta site for the whole network is [meta.se], but you should generally post to your site meta (here) and let the mods and devs take care of sending it over to MSO if necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, if a site is not present under the Migrate list, click on Flag → other (needs ♦ moderator attention) and mention to which site it should be migrated to.

We'll migrate if it fits